# Docker-Compose up -d failed to create endpoint sitecore-xp0_xconnect_1

Tags: docker

I have an issue while installing Sitecore 10 update 1 using docker, getting error as below when running command as
**docker-compose up -d**

```
xp0> docker-compose up -d       
                                                                                                       sitecore-xp0_mssql_1 is up-to-date
sitecore-xp0_solr_1 is up-to-date
sitecore-xp0_id_1 is up-to-date
Starting sitecore-xp0_xconnect_1 ... error                                                                                                                                       
ERROR: for sitecore-xp0_xconnect_1  Cannot start service xconnect: failed to create endpoint sitecore-xp0_xconnect_1 on network sitecore-xp0_default: failed during hnsCallRawResponse: hnsCall failed in Win32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x20)

ERROR: for xconnect  Cannot start service xconnect: failed to create endpoint sitecore-xp0_xconnect_1 on network sitecore-xp0_default: failed during hnsCallRawResponse: hnsCall failed in Win32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x20)
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Please suggest possible fix

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue with the **" xconnect Cannot start service xconnect: failed to create endpoint sitecore-xp0_xconnect_1 on network sitecore-xp0_default: failed during hnsCallRawResponse: hnsCall failed in Win32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."** I stopped the IIS and installed a clean instance, restarted the Docker, Killed all the ports that could be used for the solution, but still with no luck! any one could help? Is it possible of the license if it's not supported the Xconnect, will cause such an issue? Thanks, please help if y

Answer (score 11, accepted):

thanks, it actually helps to find root cause of this problem.

It was port related issue, since port was already in use.
And to verify that all ports mentioned in docker-compose.yml is not in use by any other process.
firstly  triggered **iisreset /stop** command from cmd
then ran command in powershell as
**netstat -aon | findstr 8984**

found that port was in use, then stopped solr service as well.

and tried again with `docker-compose up -d`

it resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop your IIS Service.

For more troubleshooting tips, see [Port in use / "The process cannot access the file"](https://containers.doc.sitecore.com/docs/troubleshooting#port-in-use---the-process-cannot-access-the-file) from the Sitecore Docker troubleshooting guide.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and solved the issue.

Run these commands below as an administrator in cmd:

- `net stop hns`

then

- `net start hns`